# Possible bug in Power Automate when publishing an Adaptive Card with wait for answer

Tags: power-automate

I'm facing a rather strange problem in Power Automate and I think, it is a bug.
What I am trying to do:

- initialize a variable named "Room" with "Testroom".
- Using this variable inside a Adaptive Card".
- Display a new message that the user "xyz" clicked the previously created Adaptive Card.

My Adaptive Card with wait for answer looks like this:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Test",
                        "color": "warning",
                        "size": "Medium",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "wrap": "true"
                    }
                ]
}
```

I can then see the available fields (for example "Body") of the "Adaptive Card" in the "Dynamic Content" popup.

So far, everything is fine. But very strange things happen, as soon as I am using a variable within the Adaptive Card. If I put the variable name in the Adaptive Card content, I loose all the options from the Adaptive Card in the "Dynamic Content" popup.

[Adaptive Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1JBz.png)

[Without using a variable within the Adaptive Card content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uitg0.png)

[when using a variable within the Adaptive Card content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qjDn.png)

Any advice very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely is a code defect. (So, I contacted Microsoft about it and they are sorting it out)